# Merge field in Outlook based on Y/N values in Excel field

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-word

I need to a send a bunch on emails from Outlook that reads from Word and Excel. The text content will be from Word and user_email_ID, First_Name content will be from Excel. I know how to do up to this part and have done so in the past but a new addition will be to merge some fields only based on yes/no (`Y`/`N`) from the Excel sheet. For example:

```
  Name Age Field1 Field2 Field3
  XXX   39   Y       N     Y
  YYY   29   N       N     N
  ZZZ   10   Y       Y     Y
```

In the above case, the text should look like:

for Record 1

```
Hello <Name>
       text text text, items 
       1) Field 1
       2) Field 3
```

for Record 2

```
Hello <Name>
       text text text, items 

       No Items, you are good to go.
```

for Record 3

```
Hello <Name>
       text text text, items 
       1) Field 1
       2) Field 2
       3) Field 3
```

This part should not take me much time to do in C++, or even is MySQL but I am not so quick using Microsoft products like Excel, Word, Outlook.

Can someone be kind enough to give me a heads up on which one should I start looking for in Outlook or Excel, or redirection to a relevant article please? Also, has anyone had the same problem before?

Comment: Just Office merge, How can I migrate this topic to superuser?

Comment: I'll get a moderator to do that for you, just sit tight.

Comment: Is Someone experiencing the same problem??

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the braces with Ctrl-F9 but you basically want the simple IF.  `{IF {MERGEFIELD My_Field} = "Y" "some text" ""}`.